# Visualizing parameters of a support vector machine in a scikit-learn tutorial

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm following a popular tutorial
[here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html), where I am attempting to experiment with the effect of the parameters gamma and C of the rbf kernel for a support vector machine in sci-kit learn.

With respect to the aforementioned tutorial, I am a little confused as to what the purpose of this segment of code is doing for us:

```
# dataset for decision function visualization  
X_2d = X[:, :2]
X_2d = X_2d[Y > 0]
Y_2d = Y[Y > 0]
Y_2d -= 1
```

I am assuming that we are subsetting the original data (from the iris dataset), but
why would we need to do so in the first place?  Why is the argument for `X_2d = X[:, :2]` a tuple?

If anyone familiar with this tutorial and has figured this out prior, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of code is for the purpose of visualization -- the first plot with scattered points, which shows how the decision surface changes with different training parameters. Basically it creates a smaller dataset with only two features and two classes.

`X_2d = X[:, :2]` means that `X_2d` is a dataset containing only the first two features, so that each point can be plotted conveniently (how to plot points in 4D?).

The next three lines filters out samples with label 0, so that the smaller dataset contains only two labels. It also renames the labels to either 0 or 1.